# sh: ...: is not an identifier when trying to invoke shell scripts using plink

Tags: bash, shell, unix, plink

Below is my shell script that I am trying to execute using `PLINK` on `MachineB` from `MachineA`(Windows Machine).

```
#!/bin/bash
export HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology"
hive -S -e 'SELECT count(*) from testingtable1' > attachment22.txt
```

I am using `plink` to execute the shell script like below,

```
C:\PLINK>plink uname@MachineB -m test.sh
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Your Kerberos password will expire in 73 days.
```

And this is the below error I always get whenever I try to run like above.

```
sh: HIVE_OPTS= -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology: is not 
an identifier
```

Something wrong with my shell script? or some trailing spaces? I am not able to figure it out. I am running `PLINK` from windows machine

Comment: If you created `test.sh` on your local Windows machine, you'll have to make sure the file has Unix, not Windows, line endings for it to run properly on the remote Unix host.

Comment: Thanks chepner. How can I make sure `test.sh` has unix file endings? I am using `Notepad++` to create the test.sh file and in that there is an option to create it in unix format and I did the same way.

Comment: Hm. On the remote machine, you can try `file test.sh`, and make sure it doesn't say anything about CRLF line terminators.

Comment: I've removed the update from your question. If you still want to ask about it, please post a new question (see this question's [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11693405/revisions).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `sh:` prefix on the error message indicates that the script is being executed by `sh`, not `bash`.

bash lets you combine setting a variable and exporting it into a single command:

```
export foo=bar
```

sh, or at least some older versions of it, require these two actions to be separated:

```
foo=bar ; export foo
```

A version of sh that doesn't recognize the `export foo=bar` syntax will interpret the string `foo=bar` as a variable name (and an illegal one, since it isn't an identifier).

Either arrange for the script to be executed by bash, or change this:

```
export HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology"
```

to this:

```
HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology"
export HIVE_OPTS
```

For that matter, since you're referring to `$HIVE_OPTS` at the very beginning of your script, it's almost certainly *already* exported, so you could just drop the `export`.

(You'll also need to avoid any other bash-specific features.)

So why is the system invoking the shell with sh?  The [`#!/bin/bash` syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is specific to Unix-like systems.  Windows generally decides how to execute a script based on the file extension; apparently your system is configured to invoke `*.sh` files using sh.  (You *could* configure your system, using Folder Options, to invoke `*.sh` files using bash, but that might introduce other problems.)

Comment: Thanks Keith, that fixed my previous problem, but I am getting new errors, I have updated my question with my updated shell script. it will be great if you can give some more suggestions on that.

Comment: You should open a new question for this, rather than continue here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `-m` option to `plink` is for reading commands to execute on the remote machine from a *local* file. If my comment about line endings doesn't work, try

```
plink uname@MachineB test.sh
```

Make sure `test.sh` is executable by running

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

on MachineB.